# How to pass array of strings in route?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

Here I define the route in the angular 10 project:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: component1},
  { path: 'myComponent/:dataId', component: component2}
];
```

I also have this array:

```
let myArr:string = ["5","4","7","2"]
```

In route, I pass dataId as a parameter as you can see above but I also need to pass myArr in the route as a parameter.

My question is how to pass an array of string as a parameter in route?

Comment: maybe `routerLink` can help
`routerLink="['/myComponent/:dataId/', {arrValues:[myArr}]" `

I had saved this link a while ago
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jeqbbd

Comment: the array is exactly like that or u have a complex object array ?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the array as a `queryParams` by `JSON.stringify`. And use `JSON.parse` to get the array in target page.

```
    this.route.navigate(["myComponent/id"], {
      queryParams: {
        prop: JSON.stringify(myArr)
      }
    });
```

In the myComponent

```
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(params.prop))
    })
```

if the myArr is a complex object array this might doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass your array of numbers as comma separated string to your route parameter. Something like this..

```
<a routerLink="/myComponent/1,2,3,4,5">Second Component</a>
```

And you can read the parameter, from the **activatedRoute** service snapshot and convert it back to array of numbers. Something like this.

```
this.idsArr = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.dataId
  .split(",")
  .map(x => {
    return parseInt(x);
  });
```

Here is a [working stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ffyswh?file=src/app/first/first.component.html).